# What does やついておる mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I am unsure what やついておる means in the following sentence:

> …貴様、何をにやついておるのだ…？

For some context Person A is comforting Person B who has just heard some happy news and gotten emotional. Person C says the above sentence.

I've not come across やついておる in my studies before, can someone explain this to me?

Comment: What happened to に in 何を**に**やついている?

Answer (score 3):

I think you parsed it wrong.

> 貴様、何を**にやついておる**のだ…？
>   *What are you grinning at, you bastard?*

It's [にやつく](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_niyatuku_-010/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%84%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BB%E3%81%8F/?itemid=DJR_niyatuku_-010&title=%E3%81%AB%E3%82%84%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BB%E3%81%8F) 'smirk; grin', a compound formed from the sound symbolic noun にや 'smirk; grin' along with the verb つく.

You can tell it's not 何を＋に because that sequence of particles doesn't go together.