# Using 何を with intransitive verbs (eg 何をにやついているの?)

Tags: particle-を, interrogatives

> 貴様、何をにやついておるのだ…？
>   What are you grinning at, you bastard?

This sentence (asked in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44165/5010)) seemed fairly natural and simple to me...until I realized **にやつく is an intransitive verb**. <sup>[×]</sup>彼は私をにやついた is ungrammatical. Instead, you have to say something like 彼は私を見てにやついた.

Then why is the first sentence ever possible? Well, after some pondering I came up with a similar expression:

> 何をぐっすり寝ているの、早く起きなさい！

So apparently these 何を with intransitive verbs mean *why* rather than *what*. But is that really true? I found a page where [one person says 何を can mark a reason/trigger](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=33754#p33754). But I'm not totally convinced, since all I could find was this short comment. I'd appreciate if someone explain this or point me to a longer article/reference. Should this be considered as a fixed expression like English "how come"?

(Just to be sure, as a native speaker of Japanese, I know these examples using 何を are natural, but I'm just having trouble getting a nice grammatical explanation.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

あまり詳しい説明ではないのですが、明鏡国語辞典によりますと・・・

> なに【何】
>   〘代〙
>   ❸《「ーを・・・か？」「ーを・・・のだ！」など、疑問・反語・詰問などを表す自動詞文で》不審の気持ちで、事態成立の基盤を問う。また、その不当性を非難する。どんな理由で。なぜに。なんで。 「何を泣いているのか？」「何をためらうことがあろうか」「何をぐずぐずしてるんだ！」
>   （語法）他動詞の場合は、～ヲに対する普通の疑問を表す。「何を読んでるの？」

Comment: おお、明鏡すごい！ｗ　デジタル大辞泉は探しても何もありませんでした。

Comment: My English brain doesn't get this at all. No offense.

Comment: @Wakisaka Why would you need to use English brain to understand a monolingual Japanese dictionary entry, when you have good command of Japanese? Your native language is Japanese and not English, right?

Comment: I suppose it is difficult to find the question: "Why is the 何を in first sentence ever possible?" and the answer: it is an idiom from the middle Japanese 何をか云わんや thing-ish turns into.  (not direct question and answer is written in all Japanese, hard to understand for a learner dosn't know what "反語" is) again no offense, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

(Adding my own answer for those who may run into this problem in the future)

@Shoko's answer confirmed my hypothesis. You can use 何を with intransitive verbs, and it actually means "why", "how dare you", "what makes you", etc. It usually has some dubious/accusatory tone. You can consider it a special construction.

The following example using an intransitive verb 驚く shows the difference between 何を and 何に.

- **何に**驚いているんですか？
  What are you surprised at?
  (I know you are surprised at something, but I don't know what you are surprised at.)
- **何を**驚いているんですか？
  Why are you surprised (at this)?
  (I know what you are surprised at, but I don't understand why you are surprised. "It's no wonder", "Isn't it obvious?")

Unsurprisingly, を can be omitted in casual speech: 何驚いてるんですか？

Comment: あなるほど。。この「何を」は目的語じゃないことが分かりますね。「何**を**バカなこと**を**言ってるんだ！」とか。明鏡で「を」のページを見ると、『➍「何を」+動詞+「か」などの形で⇒なに③』として、１つの項目として、他の用法とは分けて単独で載っているので、この「を」ってちょっと特殊な用法なのかな～と思いました。

Comment: @naruto Does this construction with 何を  meaning "why" only work with volitional verbs?