# How do I know which sentence is more polite?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, keigo

To say the phrase, "Teacher has arrived."

> A 先生が来られました

and

> B 先生がお越しになりました

It should have an order or a rule to compare A and B.

Comment: Why do you think a keigo sentence might be less polite than a regular masu-form sentence?

Comment: I believe 来られました is a keigo sentence. If you were to say a regular sentence, 来ました

Comment: これまでの回答を見る限り、SadaharuWakisakaさんは日本語の母語話者か、それに近い方のように見受けられるのですが、時々こういった質問をされる意図は何なのでしょう。[答えを知っていてFAQを作ろうとしている](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)のか、もの凄く専門的な話なのか、意図をつかみかねて回答しづらいことがあるのですが。

Comment: 過去の質問になかったので質問しています、国語学者ではないので答えは知りません、短期的にではなく将来誰かが同じ疑問を抱いた時に参考になるからです 例としてはどうかと思いますがhttp://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16959/which-is-more-likely-to-be-read-and-processed-related-text-placed-above-or-be?newreg=2940658dc546420eb9b07e7c8f4d3c87 を見るまで写真の上と下にキャプションを入れる時いつも迷っていました、正しい名前もわかりました

Comment: 了解です。似たことは私も[やったことがあります](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44176/5010)し全然構わないと思います。ただ「違いは知っているんだけど説明の仕方が分からない」など一言添えていただいたくと答える側が混乱せずにすむのでご検討頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, dedicated sonkeigo verbs and お～になる sound politer than ～られる.

- いらっしゃる・おいでになる・おこしになる　＞　こられる
- 召し上がる・お食べになる　＞　食べられる
- ご覧になる　＞　見られる

Answer (score 2):

Thanks ;)

In my textbook "Japanese Demystified" by Eriko Sato, it says "Another way of creating an honorific verb form is to use the same verb form as the passive form (られる etc.). However, the degree of politeness expressed by this form is lower than that expressed by the honorific form with お...になる..."

Answer (score 1):

I think the politeness oder is shown below;

先生がお越しになられました＞先生がお越しになりました＞先生が来られました

But, sorry to say, I don't know how I think so.

Comment: My question is how do you find the order.

Comment: 「お越しになられました」は二重敬語の匂いがします…

Comment: In my textbook "Japanese Demystified" by Eriko Sato, it says "Another way of creating an honorific verb form is to use the same verb form as the passive form (られる etc.). However, the degree of politeness expressed by this form is lower than that expressed by the honorific form with お...になる..."

Comment: @rgolden, please write this in the answer, I don't have a privilege to promote it.

Comment: >「お越しになられました」は二重敬語の匂いがします。私は日本人です。二重敬語であるかどうか、また二重敬語が誤った使い方かどうかも知りません。しかし、大袈裟な状況では、「お越しになられました」は「お越しになりました」より一般的に用いられているのも事実です。真摯に日本語を学ばれている外国の方に、正しい日本語を実態と照らしてどう説明するか日本人の課題ですね。broccoli forestさん勉強させていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 参考までに： 「 **二重敬語** 『ご覧になられる』『 **お越しになられる** 』→ **適切な敬語** 『ご覧になる』『 **お越しになる** 』」 ([NHK解説委員室「間違いやすい敬語」](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kaisetsu-blog/400/213917.html))、「一つの語について、同じ種類の敬語を二重に使ったものを『二重敬語』という。例えば『お読みになられる』は『読む』を『お読みになる』と尊敬語にした上で更に尊敬語『……れる』を加えたもので、二重敬語である。『二重敬語』は一般に適切ではないとされている。ただし語によっては習慣として定着しているものもある。【習慣として定着している二重敬語の例】尊敬語） お召し上がりになる，お見えになる  謙譲語Ⅰ）お伺いする，お伺いいたす，お伺い申し上げる」([文化審議会答申「敬語の指針」](http://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/sokai/sokai_6/pdf/keigo_tousin.pdf))

Comment: この二重敬語の規制は元々アナウンサーに皇室に対して使わせないようにするために設けたのであって一般人にはそもそも関係ないと思うし、学者の言うことに従う義理もない。

Comment: @Chocolate　出典を明示した丁寧なご指導ありがとうございます。習慣として定着しているものの扱いが特に、このような学習の場では難しいですね。卒業式や入学式などで「来賓の方がお越しになられました」と「来賓の方がお越しになりました」のいずれが多用（習慣化）されているか思い出しております。

Comment: @user4092 そうですか。勉強になりました。貴重な情報ありがとうございます。