# How is the use of this 何? 「何ユッキーに変なこと吹き込んでるのよ」

Tags: anime, casual

```
何ユッキーに変なこと吹き込んでるのよ
```

This sentence is from "Mirai Nikki" episode 4". I've seen this use in various animes but I don't get it quite right. It doesn't seem to be the object of the sentence since the object of 吹き込んでる is こと. It sounds more like a "why", but that's not the meaning of 何, right? It also doesn't seem to be an interjection since it's not alone in the sentence.

What is the grammatical function of this 何?

Comment: I just would like to know if that 何を can always replace that kind of 何 and if it is ommited or not in the sentence from the anime.

Comment: I posted a full answer. If you're still unsure, please comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 何を meaning "why" or "how dare you". This always sounds accusatory or dubious.

- [Using 何を with intransitive verbs (eg 何をにやついているの?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44176/5010)
- [Use of を with seemingly intransitive verbs describing emotions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93101/5010)

This type of accusatory 何を can be used with an intransitive verb. When it's used with a transitive verb, the verb can take two を (one as part of 何を and one for the actual object). Both を can be omitted in colloquial sentences.

> 何ユッキーに変なこと吹き込んでるのよ
> = 何**を**ユッキーに変なこと**を**吹き込んでるのよ
> = Why are you inculcating strange things into Yuckie?