# What does 何ちょっと mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language

The following lines come from a manga I'm reading. The male lead is a high schooler who uses a lot of truncated colloquial forms. He says the following lines, ruminating on an event where he should have stood up for his girl, but didn't, yet she doesn't appear to hold it against him.

> 何ちょっとホッとしてんだ
>
> さっき
>
> 一歩も動けなかったくせに

The first part of the first line, 何ちょっと, is what's throwing me. The rest is fine. It seems like there's a particle omitted after 何 but I'm not certain.

My main question is, how do I unpack this sentence to make sense of it? And more generally, what are some strategies for figuring out what particle (or other parts of speech or morae)is being omitted in this kind of colloquial speech?

Comment: Related: [How is the use of this 何? 「何ユッキーに変なこと吹き込んでるのよ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98099/43676), [Using 何を with intransitive verbs (eg 何をにやついているの?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44176/43676), [Use of を with seemingly intransitive verbs describing emotions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93101/43676)

Comment: The omitted particle is を, but this 何を is special.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Those do answer my original question, and now these lines are quite clear to me (having the full context of the chapter this is in). I'm still interested in answers to the more general question of how to fill in omitted bits in colloquial speech, but guess I'll have to make a new question for that.